# IE - How to disable validation detection from input after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an input that asks a user to enter a valid e-mail,  then I **clear the input** on submit.
The problem happens in IE that, if a user submitted an invalid email once, the detection feedback *(red border)* still exists even after a valid email has been submitted, because the input has been cleared.
Is there any way to stop the validation after a valid input is submitted?

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  /*
    stuff to do with the email
  */
  input.value = '';
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" required>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Also happens to me on firefox!

Comment: What you need? verify again? or only remove required dependency?

Comment: @Baksteen Doesn't happen in Chrome :'D

Comment: @osiris85 Is there any way to stop the validation after a valid input is submitted?

Comment: @Baksteen Works fine on Opera too, but thanks I didn't know that there are other browsers with this issue.

Comment: @MoaazBhnas you can use `input.removeAttributte('required')`

Comment: @osiris85 but I want it required the next time

Comment: @MoaazBhnas ok, in this case the response of scheellmax is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of clearing the input manually, you can simply reset the form after submitting:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  /*
    stuff to do with the email
  */
  //input.value = '';
  form.reset();
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" required>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: tried this via browserstack in IE11 and FF63 on Windows, as well as on my Mac in latest Chrome and Firefox, all worked. Which platforms/browser versions are you using exactly?

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I found it! looks like this can be done using CSS :)

It looks like Firefox adds a custom pseudo class to add a `box-shadow` to the input element, you can disable that as well.

I've made this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyq4wa9o/3/). My IE11 shows the "This is a required field" message, but doesn't show the red border

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  /*
    stuff to do with the email
  */
  input.value = '';
})
```

```css
/* Firefox */
input:-moz-ui-invalid{
  box-shadow:none;
}

/* Internet Explorer */
input:invalid{
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" required>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But now there isn't any feedback at all _in IE_